# Complex Conjugate of Wave Function's Derivative

Tags: homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers

I am reading Griffiths QM textbook and I got confused by the following identity:

How to prove from $$\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} = \frac{i\hbar}{2m} \frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial  x^2} - \frac{i}{\hbar}V\Psi$$ to  $$\frac{\partial \Psi^*}{\partial t} = -\frac{i\hbar}{2m} \frac{\partial^2 \Psi^*}{\partial x^2} + \frac{i}{\hbar}V\Psi^*.$$

Can anyone give me a mathematical proof of this complex conjugate identity?

Comment: Replacing $\psi$ by $\psi^*$ is wrong. Apply complex conjugation to the whole equation. Done.

Comment: I know that. But how to manipulate the sign.

Comment: Uh...$\mathrm{i}^* = -\mathrm{i}$? No sign manipulation needed.